# Angular 5 build breaks bootstrap cards responsivness

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a problem where I have several bootstrap cards. In my Angular 5 dev-environment the cards work well, The column-count of 8, puts 8 cards on one row and if I squeeze the screen, card size gets smaller, and eventually will switch to 4 card rows with correct card size.

But when I build the Angular 5 app and run this in production, the card sizes do not change. The columns basically work (8 -> 4) when screen is squeezed, but the cards go off the display, because their size does not change.

Any ideas? I first thought that switching to support es5 (IE and old Safari) caused this, but after testing, this was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the cards do not work as expected, especially with images. So you have to manually limit the amount of columns and just try out what fits. So my misunderstanding basically.